# Sort List Based On Custom User Settings

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sorting, nsarray

I'm working on an app where a user can upload and download information.  The information is downloaded in such a way that when it's downloaded, it's ordered according to when it was submitted.

What I'd like is for the user to be able to reorganize the table view, save the order to a preference file (all ready working) and from now on, whenever data is request, the order now conforms to the users re-organized list.

Maybe my brains just fried, but is there an array function that can accomplish this, or am I on my own?  Any suggestions how to go about writing something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [`NSSortDescriptor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [originalArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                            [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                             [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"keyToBeSorted"
                                                          ascending:YES
                                                           selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease]]];
```